# how can i sort elements of a list which are string by using filter in kotlin? whats wrong in my approach?

Tags: kotlin

```
val spices = listOf("curry", "pepper", "cayenne", "ginger", "red curry", "green curry", "red pepper" )    
spices.filter { it }.sortedBy { it.length }
```

error: type inference failed: inline fun  Iterable.filter(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List
cannot be applied to
receiver: List  arguments: ((String) -> String)

spices.filter { it }.sortedBy { it.length }
       ^
error: type mismatch: inferred type is (String) -> String but (String) -> Boolean was expected
spices.filter { it }.sortedBy { it.length }

Comment: Well, filtering a collection consists in only keeping some elements of the collection that pass a given predicate. I have no idea what you want to do here. You don't need to filter a list to sort it. BTW, Kotlin functions are documented: why don't you read the documentation?

Comment: Filtering and sorting are two different things. 
Are sure you want to filter at all? If yes, for what do you want to filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter needs a predicate inside brackets, `it` is not a predicate.
You don't need filter to sort the list

Just do:

```
val spices = mutableListOf<String>("curry", "pepper", "cayenne", "ginger", "red curry", "green curry", "red pepper" )
spices.sortBy { it.length }
```

Also change from `listOf` to `mutableListOf`

Answer (score 3):

`filter` requires a predicate returning a boolean. See the declaration:

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.filter(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<T> {
    return filterTo(ArrayList<T>(), predicate)
}
```

`(T) -> Boolean` means it returns a boolean and takes an input of type T. `T` is `it` in this case.

A string is not a boolean. If you actually have a List of Booleans though, you could do this:

```
val list = listOf(true, true, false, true, true, false )
val sortedList = list.filter{ it }
```

and it would be valid, because it is a boolean. However, with all other types, you need to convert it to a boolean operation, if you intend to do filtering.

However, since you don't actually seem to do any filtering, just remove it and do this:

```
val sortedList = spices.sortedBy { it.length }
```

and if you have to filter it somehow, make sure you get a boolean operation or value.

In order to actually sort it, you have to do something with the value `sortedBy`. In my example, I assign it to a new field, but you can also assign it to the previous field. However, if you do this, you have to make it a `var` and not a `val`.

Answer (score 2):

the second line of code should be:

```
val curry = spices.filter { it.contains("curry", true) }
```

On top of that we need the curry list to be sorted bij length. Using the (.) operator and sortedBy() gives an error:

```
val currySorted = spices.filter { it.contains("curry", true) }.sortedBy { it.length }
```

Is there a way to sort the filtered list in one go?

Update: the .sortedBy method works fine. The display of the result is weird in REPL:

```
for (i in 0..currySorted.size-1) println(currySorted[i])
```

gives the following result in REPL:
Curryred currygreen curry

Watching more precisely it is ordered! but REPL contatinates the strings in the output: Curry, Red curry, green curry

By the way, this assignment comes from the Kotlin Bootcamp course by Udacity

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing the same course and what worked for me was:

```
spices.filter { it.contains("curry") }.sortedBy { it.length }.reversed()
```

It will first look for all the entries with "curry", than sort it by shortest to longest and then you simply reverse the order.

Answer (score 0):

"filter" needs a Boolean expression ,So If you insist on using "filter" to sort the list ,you should make a predicate.

```
val spices = mutableListOf<String>("curry", "pepper", "cayenne", "ginger", "red curry", "green curry", "red pepper" )    
spices.filter { it.isNotEmpty() }.sortedBy { it.length }
```

Otherwise you could get rid of "filter" and use "sortedBy" directly